# Puppeteer get through chrome connexion message popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-scraping, puppeteer

[image]

Hi, im trying to connect my router web interface with puppeteer, but obviously this kind of message appears, ( it says " Open a session" and "Your connexion to this website is not private" )

I cant have any interaction with it since it is not HTML code.
How could i manege to connect to the interface ?
Cant we connect with something in the URL like http://192.168.2.127:username:password ?

Thanks you for reading this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic authentication credentials can be passed via URL like this:

```
http://username:password@192.168.2.127
```

In `puppeteer` you may use `page.authenticate` method:

```
await page.authenticate({username: login, password: password)
```